# Localizer in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, localization

I'm currently stuck trying to have multiples languages on my website when it has to be in an @Html.ActionLink.
Just a precision, it work for everything else, it load the good culture and displays the good language everywhere else.

What I already tried to solve it :

Put all the @Html.ActionLink... in the .resx file.
Look at the Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core from Microsoft Docs
Do like this example code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto mt-1">
    <li class="nav-item" id="Register" style="padding-right:20px;">
        @Html.ActionLink(Localizer["Register"], "Index", "Register", null, new { @style = "color:white" })
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="Login">            
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "/Account/Login", "Identity", null, new { @style = "color:white" })
    </li>
</ul>
```

So my question is: How can i get the language to change with a @Html.ActionLink message by culture?

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `Localizer["Register"].Value`